# How does LIME compares with Mutual Information?

Tags: interpretation, mutual-information, explanatory-models, lime

So, I was wondering how LIME's linear model approach compares with other explanation metrics, in special, with Mutual Information? 
For those unfamiliar with how LIME works:

1. Choose the instance you want to explain
2. Probe your model with a few perturbations on that instance
3. Fit a linear model to those points, points closer to the original instance are worth more (weighted heavier)
4. You can now look to the (simpler) linear model, instead of your RBF-kernel SVM (much harder to interpret)

What would be advantages and disadvantages of using a different "model" in step 3, in this, calculating the mutual information of the model-assigned label and each of the features?

Comment: Can you please also provided references about how mutual information is used to explain individual predictions? I am only aware of the *very* recent work of Chen et al. but that's about it...

Comment: In this case in particular, instead of fitting a linear model to the probed instances, one would instead compute how much information each feature provides for determining the model-assigned label, again, probed instances would be weighted heavier if they are closer to the instance that is being explained, for reference, here is the LIME repo: https://github.com/marcotcr/lime, the general approach here is replacing the Linear model with the Mutual Information as a mean to assign feature importance values. My question is: is there any reason to prefer this over Linear models?

Comment: Apologies, Maybe I was unclear, I am not asking about LIME; I am asking about the MI part of your question. Where have you seen a methodology using it to explain individual predictions.